# d3 collapsible tree path text

Tags: d3.js, tree

I am new to D3.  I am using the awesome Collapsible Tree example (https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd) and I am trying to get text to show up on the paths connecting each node.  For example, I would like to write "foo" on the line connecting "Top Level" and "Level 2: A", and then I would like to write "bar" on the line connecting "Top Level" and "Level 2: B".

I see the links section below in the code...

```
// ****************** links section ***************************

// Update the links...
var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
    .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr('d', function(d){
      var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
      return diagonal(o, o)
    });
```

But I am unsure of how to add text to these links.  If anyone could help or give me any clues, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Since you want different text depending on the links, the text you want will have to be a part of the `"children"` in the treeData object. You will have to then create a group for the links and then append the text to the group.